# Can you create "product order numbers" and "ID" numbers is mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm new to coding and need help, I want to record new orders in mysql so and order is posted to the mysql database from php I believe the php code should look like:

```
$p_account = $_POST['account'];
$p_account_id = $_POST['accountid'];
$p_email = $_POST['email'];
$p_id = $_POST['id'];
$p_name = $_POST['name'];
$p_width = $_POST['width'];
$p_height = $_POST['height'];
$p_price = $_POST['price'];
$p_order_id = $_POST['orderid'];
$p_date = $_POST['date'];
$p_quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$p_product = $_POST['product'];
$p_product_id = $_POST['productid'];
```

However I'm having trouble, not with posting the data such as email, price, name, width, heigh, data, product ID or product which are inputed or are permanent

I'm having trouble with for example the "ID" numbers.

I want it so the id a new user joins they get an account ID which is invisible to the user but when they log in in a different location they can post the rest of the information. Then when it posts the product data it generates a new order number which I want to set so Order number would be 1001 then +1 every time a new post with all posts above are posted.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need control over the order numbers, or can they be auto-generated by the database?  Take a look at the `auto-increment` feature in mysql/phpmyadmin for ID fields.  You would create a record and populate all the fields except the ID, and it would be generated automatically, which you can then retrieve from the database.

Comment: You need to reformat the question a bit so that everyone can understand better. I can understand the question regards to order number which you can solve by `auto-increment` but what was the other question ?

Comment: auto-increment will work if i can set the number it starts at? I'm not sure on how to structure the database. As ideally i want the User to have their user ID which is auto-incrmented, then their email and password, then would it be best to have it on a separate table for orders and link them up using the user ID? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create the database:

```
CREATE TABLE jos_xxxx
(
Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
account varchar(255) NOT NULL,
accountid varchar(255),
email varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

You can insert the values like this

```
INSERT INTO jos_xxxx (account,accountid,email) VALUES ('qwe1','12',test@test.com)
```

The value of the `Id` is automatically incremented